# how to check if backgroundimage of UIbutton is added or not

Tags: iphone, uiimage, uibutton

I want to check how to check if backgroundimage of UIbutton is present or not

I have code,

```
[Button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_module.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I want to check if there is image named "default_module.png" present and included in project folder or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do this:

```
if(![UIImage imageNamed:@"default_module"]){
     //The image was not present. Act accordingly.
}else{
    //Continue as normal
}
```

Comment: ohh, i got it now its working, a bit mistake from my side. Thanks Aurum